# Comaprison of two integers fields in view model on post

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel

**I have two fields in my view model**

```
 public decimal Rate { get; set; }
 public decimal GrossRate { get; set; }
```

Gross rate should be greater than or equal to Rate.
Validate that whether gross rate is equal or greater than rate if gross rate enter is less it will display error message.
Is there is something possible that I can validate from view model. I dont want to use if statement on postback.

Comment: Check out FluentValidation.NET or the default MVC Data Annotations mechanism.

Comment: Or use a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[GreaterThanOrEqualTo]` or similar validation attribute

Comment: I use [ExpressiveAnnotations](https://github.com/jwaliszko/ExpressiveAnnotations) for stuff like this. You can then decorate your GrossRate property with a AssertThat attribute with the relevant condition.